# Delete event (transaction ) in sentry coming from specific endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sentry

This is an example of my sentry init method where I'm trying to delete events coming from /status API but the event is not detected. I'm using node js app

```
beforeSend(event) {
    // filter the event here
    if (event.transaction === "GET /status") {
      // Don't send events coming from /status endpoint
      delete event 
    } else {
      return event
    }
},
```